# Differentiation under the integral sign in higher dimensions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, matrix-analysis, leibniz-integral-rule

Let's say I have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Are there conditions under which the following holds

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}\int_\Omega f(\mathbf{x},t) \,{\rm d} t = \int_\Omega \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}f(\mathbf{x},t) \,{\rm d} t,$$

where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ is some open set? In this case, both the LHS and RHS quantities are in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

For $n=1$ there are results that follow from Lebesgue Dominated Convergence, but I am unaware of results in higher dimensions. Intuitively, it seems like the extension shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: Wikipedia covers the matter quite satisfactorily: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Higher_dimensions

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte, that considers higher dimensions in a different sense, i.e. multidimensional integrals and integration of a scalar function with respect to single variable. The integral I consider is one dimensional, but I have a vector derivative of a vector valued function.

Comment: Unless you're asking about $n\rightarrow \infty $, your objects are just linear combinations of finitely many $n=1$ objects.

Comment: @RS-Coop Yes, I got confused by the use of $\Omega$ as an open subset of the reals. But in that case the comment by Michael Engelhardt applies, no?

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte, Perhaps you can clarify in an answer how the comment by Michael applies? Indeed I am only concerned with finite $n$.

Comment: I think the comment "your objects are just linear combinations of finitely many $n=1$ objects" doesn't quite make sense, but I think it is getting at an approach of reducing the problem to 1D, so I will take a stab at formalizing that in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal will be to reduce to 1D, so that we can apply that standard differentiation under the integral sign, which I will call DIS. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) for quick reference on this result.

Assume the following:

1. For almost all $t\in\Omega$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}f(\mathbf{x},t)$ exists for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$
2. $f(\mathbf{x},t)$ is integrable w.r.t $t$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$
3. $||\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}f(\mathbf{x},t)||_2\leq g(t)$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and almost all $t\in\Omega$, where $g$ is an integrable function

From 3, we can conclude the following for $i,j=1,\ldots,n$:
$$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}f(\mathbf{x},t)\Big)_{ij}\leq||\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}f(\mathbf{x},t)||_{max}\leq||\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}f(\mathbf{x},t)||_2\leq g(t)$$
for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and almost all $t\in\Omega$. Now, apply DIS to yield the following:
$$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}\int_\Omega f(\mathbf{x},t)\ dt\Big)_{ij}=\Big(\int_\Omega \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}^T}f(\mathbf{x},t)\ dt\Big)_{ij}$$

Then we can conclude that the two matrices in question are equal via equality of their elements.